# I want to use HTML Form input values in ActionScript 3 by using ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, forms, externalinterface

I have an HTML Form and a SWF file on the same page. I want the user to enter some values in an html form, click send and have the values sent to the swf for populating (No Refresh of the page, and I would like to use AJAX/JSON but I cannot.) I cannot get this to work. At this point I just want to write the javascript variables or at least parse the JS Object onto the artboard of the swf. Once that works I can go far.

HTML:

```
<article>
        <aside>
            <div class="box">
                <form id="submit2swf" name="submit2swf"> 
                    <label>Link 1:</label>
                    <input name="link1" value="www.google.com" />
                    <label>Link 2:</label>
                    <input name="link2" value="www.autotrader.com" />
                    <label>Link 3:</label>
                    <input name="link3" value="www.webgraphicsatlanta.com" />
                    <label>Give this a string:</label>
                    <textarea name="string" placeholder="Default string is empty variable..."></textarea>
                </form>
                <div id="send2swf" class="button">Send this data to the SWF</div>
            </div>
        </aside><aside>
            <div class="box">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="300" height="300" id="dogs" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="dogs/dogs.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object id="flashMovie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="dogs/dogs.swf" width="300" height="300">
                    <param name="movie" value="dogs/dogs.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>    
            </div>
        </aside>
    </article>
```

The JS:

```
function sendData(){
    inputs = $('#submit2swf :input'),
    urls = {};
    inputs.each(function() {
        urls[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(urls);
    return urls;
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#send2swf').on('click',function(){
        sendData();
    });
});
```

The AS3:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var retval:int = ExternalInterface.call("sendData()", "urls");
var str = retval.toString();

var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
myTextBox.text = str;    
addChild(myTextBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data to swf, you need to register callback in actionscript first.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("setUrls", setUrls);

private function setUrls(urls:String) {
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
    myTextBox.text = str;    
    addChild(myTextBox); 
}
```

Then you need to invoke it from javascript.

```
function sendData(){
    inputs = $('#submit2swf :input'),
    urls = {};
    inputs.each(function() {
        urls[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(urls);
    $('dogs').setUrls(urls);
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: on this line:  $('dogs').setUrls(urls);

Comment: @DJERock What browser are you using for testing?